# CSS not getting applied in wicked_pdf for rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

The pdf is generated without any CSS to it.
I have used the following code :

In gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 2.1'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

in controllers/product_controller - show action

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "product_pdf",
        template: "products/show.html.erb",
        layout: 'pdf.html'
      end
    end
```

I have made a new file called pdf.html.erb in app/views/layout :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PDF</title>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "styles" -%>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am rendering it in product/show.html.erb

```
<p id="pdf_link"><%= link_to "Download Solution", product_path(@product, :format => "pdf") %></p>
```

Need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what my stylesheet import would look like:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64 "styles" %>
```

The styles.scss (or .css) file should be located in the app/assets/stylesheets/ folder

Comment: My _styles.scss file is in app/assets/stylesheets/ folder. I used the above code and error is thrown which says - Could not find asset 'styles'

Comment: Does it work if you change the file name to styles.scss?

Comment: Is `styles` in your asset precompile list?

Comment: @Libby it is named styles.scss. It is a partial though '_styles.scss'